# How to insert every string character to two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I've made two dimensional array

```
rows, columns = (5, 4)
table = [["" for i in range(columns)] for j in range(rows)]
```

now I want to insert every string character to it

```
string = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
```

I want this output :
[['a', 'a', 'a', ''], ['b', 'b', '', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', ''], ['d', '', 'e', 'e'], ['e', '', '', '']]

I tried something like this in many ways but it throws an error.

```
 for i in range(len(string)):
        table[columns][rows] = string[i]
```

Comment: Please add the error message and what is unclear about it.

Comment: please don't use 'list' as variable. it's a bad practice. also you're calling kolumns not columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rows, columns = (5, 4)
table = [["" for i in range(columns)]for j in range(rows)]
string = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
for i in range(len(string)):
    table[i // columns][i % columns] = string[i]
print(table)
```

Comment: *str* ? Are you sure you want to use that as a variable name?

Comment: fair point. @OlvinRoght missed it. my bad

Answer (score 1):

With your *table* and *string*

```
rows, columns = (5, 4)
table = [['' for i in range(columns)] for j in range(rows)]
string = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
```

you can set elements of *table* to letters of *string* while looping rows of *table*.

```
str_iter = iter(string)
for row in table:
    for e, (_, row[e]) in enumerate(zip(row, str_iter)): ...

print(table)
```

Output

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', ' '],
 ['b', 'b', ' ', 'c'],
 ['c', 'c', 'c', ' '],
 ['d', ' ', 'e', 'e'],
 ['e', '', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy's `array.reshape` and `str.ljust`:

```py
import numpy as np

mystring = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
n_rows, n_columns = (5, 4)

table = np.array(list(mystring.ljust(n_rows*n_columns))).reshape(n_rows, n_columns)

print(table)
# [['a' 'a' 'a' ' ']
#  ['b' 'b' ' ' 'c']
#  ['c' 'c' 'c' ' ']
#  ['d' ' ' 'e' 'e']
#  ['e' ' ' ' ' ' ']]
```

Using more_itertools' `grouper`, ignoring the number of rows and assuming there is less than one full row of spaces to add:

```py
from more_itertools import grouper

mystring = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
n_columns = 4

table = list(grouper(mystring, n_columns, fillvalue=' '))

print(table)
# [('a', 'a', 'a', ' '),
#  ('b', 'b', ' ', 'c'),
#  ('c', 'c', 'c', ' '),
#  ('d', ' ', 'e', 'e'),
#  ('e', ' ', ' ', ' ')]
```

Using more_itertools' `chunked` with `str.ljust`:

```py
from more_itertools import chunked

mystring = "aaa bb cccc d eee"
n_rows, n_columns = 6, 4

table = list(chunked(mystring.ljust(n_rows*n_columns), n_columns))

print(table)
# [['a', 'a', 'a', ' '],
#  ['b', 'b', ' ', 'c'],
#  ['c', 'c', 'c', ' '],
#  ['d', ' ', 'e', 'e'],
#  ['e', ' ', ' ', ' '],
#  [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```